# Ag-Grid apply state in server side

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I wonder how I can implement restore state in server side render
here is my code where `setColumnState` and  `columnState` come from redux

but seems its not working with server side I got this error

> AG Grid: ImmutableService only works with ClientSideRowModel

code

```
interface AgGridTableProps extends GridOptions {
  keyField: string;
  onRowClick: (id: number) => void;
  pageSize: number;
  loadData: (
    params: IServerSideGetRowsRequest
  ) => Promise<{ rowData: any; rowCount: number }>;
  setColumnState: (columns: ColumnState[]) => void;
  columnState: ColumnState[];
}

function AgGridTable({
  columnDefs,
  pageSize,
  keyField,
  onRowClick,
  loadData,
  setColumnState,
  columnState,
  ...rest
}: AgGridTableProps) {
  const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact<unknown>>(null);

  const defaultColDef: ColDef = useMemo(
    () => ({
      resizable: true,
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      checkboxSelection: isFirstColumn,
    }),
    []
  );
  const sideBar = useMemo<SideBarDef | string | string[] | boolean | null>(
    () => sideBarColumnOnly(),
    []
  );
  const datasource: IServerSideDatasource = {
    getRows: (params: IServerSideGetRowsParams) => {
      loadData(params.request)
        .then((response) => {
          params.success({
            rowData: response.rowData,
            rowCount: response.rowCount,
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          params.fail();
        });
    },
  };
  const onGridReady = useCallback((params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    // register datasource with the grid
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  }, []);

  const onSaveGridColumnState = () => {
    const currentColumnState = gridRef?.current?.columnApi.getColumnState();
    console.log('currentColumnState', currentColumnState);
    if (currentColumnState) setColumnState(currentColumnState);
  };

  const onFirstDataRendered = (params: any) => {
    if (columnState) {
      params.columnApi.applyColumnState({
        state: columnState,
      });
    }
  };
  console.log('columnState', columnState);

  const onRowSelected = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: '60%', width: '100%' }}>
      <AgGridReact
        ref={gridRef}
        rowModelType="serverSide"
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        sideBar={sideBar}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        paginationPageSize={pageSize}
        pagination
        rowSelection="multiple"
        cacheBlockSize={pageSize}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        onRowSelected={onRowSelected}
        serverSideInitialRowCount={pageSize}
        onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
        onRowClicked={(event: any) => onRowClick(event.data[keyField])}
        getRowId={(params: GetRowIdParams<any>) => params.data[keyField]}
        getRowNodeId={(params: GetRowIdParams<any>) => params.data[keyField]}
        onColumnVisible={onSaveGridColumnState}
        onColumnPinned={onSaveGridColumnState}
        onColumnResized={onSaveGridColumnState}
        onColumnMoved={onSaveGridColumnState}
        {...rest}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AgGridTable;
```

Ref:https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-state/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the same issue please wrap `onFirstDataRendered` on `useCallback` to be like this

```
const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback((params: FirstDataRenderedEvent) => {
    if (columnState) {
      params.columnApi.applyColumnState({
        state: columnState,
        applyOrder: true,
      });
    }
  }, []);
```